# websocket-client: failed CONNECT via proxy status: 503

Tags: python, websocket

I'm testing basic code, and it is working, as it should

```
import websocket 

ws = websocket.WebSocket()
ws.connect("wss://echo.websocket.org/")
send_string = "Testing WebSocket"
print "Sending: ",send_string
ws.send(send_string)
result = ws.recv()
print "Received: ",result
ws.close()
```

But after changing websocket address to my desire "wss://10.240.118.148:51443/ws/" I have:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testws.py", line 5, in <module>
    ws.connect("wss://10.240.118.148:51443/ws/")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/websocket/_core.py", line 213, in connect
    options.pop('socket', None))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/websocket/_http.py", line 72, in connect
    sock = _tunnel(sock, hostname, port, auth)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/websocket/_http.py", line 224, in _tunnel
    "failed CONNECT via proxy status: %r" % status)
websocket._exceptions.WebSocketProxyException: failed CONNECT via proxy status: 503
```

Of course connection to websocket is working:

```
wscat -n -c wss://10.240.118.148:51443/ws/

connected (press CTRL+C to quit)
> test

< {"error":{"code":-32700,"data":"parse error - unexpected 't'","message":"Parse error"},"id":null,"jsonrpc":"2.0"}
```

Do you have any idea what can be wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

"failed CONNECT via proxy status: 503 is"  really is a server error and not a Proxy error, you would have to consult your server's error log files to find out the reason for the problem.